# DLL Code injection to third party process using QueueUserAPC

Tags: dll-injection

I want to inject my dll in to 64 bit application and I have tried the logic explained in the given  [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2017/03/14/injecting-a-dll-without-a-remote-thread/#comment-2836310) using QueueUserAPC. I am getting success message for every API but when I see in ProcessExplorer I am not able to see my dll in the process.
Below is my code :

```
bool FindProcess(PCWSTR exeName, DWORD& pid, vector<DWORD>& tids) {
auto hSnapshot = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return false;
pid = 0;
PROCESSENTRY32 pe = { sizeof(pe) };
if (::Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe)) {
    do {
        if (_wcsicmp(pe.szExeFile, exeName) == 0) {
            pid = pe.th32ProcessID;
            THREADENTRY32 te = { sizeof(te) };
            if (::Thread32First(hSnapshot, &te)) {
                do {
                    if (te.th32OwnerProcessID == pid) {
                        tids.push_back(te.th32ThreadID);
                    }
                } while (::Thread32Next(hSnapshot, &te));
            }
            break;
        }
    } while (::Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe));
}
::CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
return pid > 0 && !tids.empty();}



void main(){
DWORD pid;
vector<DWORD> tids;
if (FindProcess(L"DataGrid.exe", pid, tids))
{
    printf("OpenProcess\n");
    HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, pid);
    printf("VirtualAllocEx\n");
    auto p = ::VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nullptr, 1 << 12, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    wchar_t buffer[] = L"C:\\Users\\sbhuma\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\GalaxyHook\\Debug\\GalaxyHook.dll";
    printf("WriteProcessMemory\n");
    ::WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, p, buffer, sizeof(buffer), nullptr);
    for (const auto& tid : tids)
    {
        printf("OpenThread\n");
        HANDLE hThread = ::OpenThread(THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, FALSE, tid);
        if (hThread)
        {
            printf("GetProcAddress\n");
            DWORD word = ::QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC)::GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "LoadLibraryW"), hThread, (ULONG_PTR)p);
            if (word)
            {
                printf("insdie if\n");
            }
            printf("End of IF\n");
        }
    }
    printf("VirtualFreeEx\n");
    ::VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, p, 0, MEM_RELEASE | MEM_DECOMMIT);
}}
```

Any help related to inject the dll in to 64 bit application is helpful as I am new to this topic.

Regards,

Sowmya.

Comment: Is the space intentional in this string?: `wchar_t buffer[] = L" C:\\...`

Comment: i have removed space and tried , still no luck

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ensure you’re building your injector app as 64 bit.

One possible reason is you’re releasing the buffer too early. QueueUserAPC doesn’t wait; it enqueues the call and returns immediately. Can be your injector process ends running that `for` loop, calls `VirtualFreeEx`, then your target process receives the APC, tries to load your DLL but the name buffer is already released by then, so LoadLibrary fails. To verify, comment out the call to VirtualFreeEx. If your DLL will load OK, one way to fix the memory leak is use a named event, `CreateEvent` in injector app before any calls to QueueUserAPC(), `OpenEvent`, `SetEvent` and `CloseHandle` in DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) of the DLL you’re injecting, `WaitForSingleObject` in injector app before `VirtualFreeEx`, I recommend using a timeout for the wait, `CloseHandle` at the end. As a side effect, your injector app will be able to find out, and report somewhere, whether the injection was successful.

Another possible reason is your target app never enters alertable state. Not all apps use APC, there’re multiple alternative methods to implement asynchronous stuff in Windows. So, not all apps ever call these SleepEx / WaitForMultipleObjectsEx functions. Such app will never receive that APC. If that’s the case, you should use another method of DLL injection. DataGrid.exe name hints your target app is probably a GUI app. You can `EnumWindows` or `FindWindow` to find its top-level window, `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get thread ID who owns that window, `SetWindowsHookEx` to inject your DLL into the target process.